# How do I tell if there are two versions of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I know that if I have two versions of jQuery running, I can run `$.noConflict(true)` to resolve some issues. What I don't know, is how to determine using jQuery/javascript whether I have two versions of jQuery running. I have searched Google and StackOverflow but the only results were how to resolve the conflict, not how to detect it.

As a bonus question, how do I control which jQuery version I am removing from `$` when I call `$.noConflict(true)`? The example here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/#example-4 says that the second one is removed, but what if we don't know which order the jQuery libraries are loaded in? Could we specify which version we want to unbind from `$`?

Comment: I would think that you can't have 2 versions of jQuery running. That each would override the `jQuery` and `$` global variables, and as such, the `$.noConflict(true)` wouldn't matter. The purpose of noConflict is for other libraries that depend on `$` variable.

Comment: Why do you have two versions of jQuery?

Comment: @SunnyPatel  You can have two versions of jquery running. Not that it's a good idea. Sometimes, third-party ad trackers load in their own version of jquery. Or you may have widgets on a page that use their own sets of libraries.

Comment: @SunnyPatel if you look at the example from the jQuery API that I linked to, you will see that they specifically show how to handle two versions of jQuery, using noConflict.

Comment: @Ibu I have the jQuery that I load on the whole site, but on some pages an analyst is using a web intercept to add a widget that brings its own version of jQuery. As a result, when I try to access a jQuery plugin I get the error $(...).validate() is not a function because the plugin is attached to one version of jQuery but the $ variable is tied to the other.

Comment: Someone posted an example as an answer with a quote from jQuery API, but I have no experience in this since I never have the urge to load multiple versions of jQuery on a page.